# iCloud Drive - sync Documents without syncing Desktop?

Tags: icloud

I want to use iCloud Drive syncing for my Documents folder, but I do not want to sync my Desktop. Is there a way to sync only Documents?

Very often I copy large video files to Desktop for processing, editing, etc. Syncing these temporary files uses a lot of bandwidth and slows down other uploads.

---

Symmetrical question:

- [Sync only Desktop folder, but not Documents, with "Store in iCloud"? (iCloud Drive)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253647/sync-only-desktop-folder-but-not-documents-with-store-in-icloud-icloud-dri)

Related support thread:

- https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7679836

System Preferences:

[image: iCloud Desktop & Documents Folders]

Comment: Can't you simply store your large video files in a different folder, one that you don't sync to iCloud?

Comment: ```desktop``` is a convenient location because it is ```desktop```. It is easier to dump files there, without thinking too much.

Comment: I did a little research and can't find how to disconnect `desktop` from `documents`.  Maybe someone else here will know how to do that.  While waiting for a better answer, at least you have a workaround.

Comment: Hahaha... Of course not putting files to desktop is a workaround but it is not convenient. Dragging files from SD card or anything really directly to desktop is much more convenient :)

Comment: Couldn't you just reverse the answer to the ["symmetrical question" you linked](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/253647)? Uncheck the "Desktop & Documents Folders" option, then move `Documents` to the `Library/Mobile Documents` directory (which still gets synced because the per-app directories all live there) and symlink that to where `Documents` originally was. Granted, that answer is unconfirmed, but to my knowledge it should work.

Comment: If you uncheck the "Desktop & Documents Folders" good luck on checking it back. I can't get the checkbox to remain checked.

Answer (score 1):

Put your large video files into Downloads.
This is what I do for instructional videos from Lynda
Don't sync or use iCloud Drive for Downloads

Comment: Welcome to [apple.se]! This could be a valid (but rather obvious) workaround; I assume the author puts their files on the Desktop for a reason (ease of access).

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I use Desktop for thousands of other reasons, large video files is one of them. `I want to use iCloud drive, but I want to disable Desktop.`